# iPhone problem while updating app to 3.0

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, permissions

I have recently updated my xcode and installed iphone sdk 3.0 GM Seed. I am trying to build my 2.2.1-application in 3.0, but I get a bunch of errors - mostly permission denied-errors. Here is one of them:

> Unable to write to file
>   /Users/hansespenskorpen/jobb/rac/build/rac.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/rac.build/Objects-normal/i386/rac.LinkFileList
>   (You do not have appropriate access
>   privileges to save file
>   “rac.LinkFileList” in folder “i386”.)

Does anyone else experienced the same problem?
Thanks in advance, Hans Espen

Answer (score 1):

Try cleaning the build first.

Comment: I did that, but it didn't do any difference. What I had to do was to create a new project and copy all the classes into that project. Then i got it working :)